# How can I use mulitple inheritance in Solidity?

Tags: solidity

I want to inherit from multiple sources.
If I only want to use ERC20 it looks like this:

```
contract MyContract is ERC20 {

   function myFunction() public {
      ...
   }
}
```

How do I use now the Ownable from OpenZeppelin aswell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just separate it by a comma.
It looks like this:

```
contract MyContract is ERC20, Ownable {

   function myFunction() public {
      ...
   }
}
```